# How To Select in mysql from Starting date

Tags: mysql

How can I select range of dates between start Date to Maximum date available in the table (Ex. starting from 03-05-2016 to highest date available in the table).

I failed in

```
select x from y where date between a and b
```

as I have no value for b (end date).

I added the full code, I used >= but the statement has something has something wrong. It echo "Failed"

```
$StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ActivityDate, ANCO, CoreSite, MailSubject, AssignedDCO, Notes FROM ActivityPlanner WHERE ActivityDate >= ?"))
{
$stmt->bind_param("s", $StartDate);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ActivityDate, $ANCO, $CoreSite, $MailSubject, $AssignedDCO, $Notes);
while ($stmt->fetch()) 
{
$Str = strval($ANCO);
echo json_encode($Str).",".json_encode($CoreSite).",".json_encode($MailSubject).",".json_encode($AssignedDCO).",".json_encode($Notes).",".json_encode($ActivityDate).",";
}
$stmt->close();
echo ("Successfull");
}
else{
echo ("Failed");
$mysqli->close();  
}
```

Comment: `date BETWEEN a AND b` is *equivalent* to `date >= a AND date <= b`.  See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `BETWEEN` when you *know* the range.  For your scenario, you can just simply use `>` or `>=`.

```
-- Note: Dates need to be in the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'
SELECT x FROM y WHERE date >= '2016-03-05'
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems not working with php prepared statement, please take a look on the code that I added

Answer (score 2):

This query will result date from 03-05-2016 to maximum date in your table

Select x from table where date > '2016-05-03'

Comment: I've added the code as I am using prepared statement but this is not working .. kindly take a look on it